# Loop delays for http request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm the newbie in Jmeter.I have the next task: X thread groups which send 2 different http request and the same http request with delaying 6sec. X> 50 000, Y> 100. I can`t find the solution for delaying Y http requests. Now, my test plan has the next look:

```
Thread Group (X)
     HTTP Request (1)
     HTTP Request (2)
     Loop Controller (Y times)
      -> Http Request
```

How can I solve my task? I would be grateful to everyone who can direct me to right way

Comment: You just want 6 sec delay before HTTP Request?

Comment: Yes, in HTTP request which in Loop Controller. But delay must be after each HTTP Request which in Loop Controller. I've tried Constant Timer, but it wasn`t work as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Anton,

The most appropriate solution would be to use [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) element of JMeter with pause option set to 6000 ms. [image]

This element needs to be placed before the 'HTTP Request' in your [loop controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) as mentioned below:

- HTTP Request (1)
- HTTP Request (2)
- Loop Controller (Y times)

  - Test Action
  - Http Request

Here are few tips that can help you to optimize the [JMeter test plan](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/10/8-tips-for-optimizing-jmeter-test-plans/)

Comment: This is now called `Flow Control Action`

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) **as a child** of the last HTTP Request like:

- Thread Group

  - HTTP Request (1)
  - HTTP Request (2)
  - Loop Controller

    - HTTP Request

      - Constant Timer

and set "Thread Delay" to `6000`.

Be aware that you will not be able to see the "delay" anywhere as by default duration of PreProcessors, PostProcessors and Timers is not included into "Elapsed" time of the Sample Result (unless you use [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) in "Generate Parent Sample" mode and "Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample").

Constant Timer will pause each thread for 6 seconds **before** each Y HTTP Request.

If you need the pause to be **after** the request - add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler after the Y HTTP Request

- Thread Group

  - HTTP Request (1)
  - HTTP Request (2)
  - Loop Controller

    - HTTP Request
    - Test Action

  and configure it to pause `Current Thread` for `6000` milliseconds